# Sum of rows (with NA's) in R

Tags: r, sum, summarize

I have a data.frame "data" with the columns "var1" ... "var3". Now, I'd like to calculate a new column "sum" from the three var-columns. Unfortunately, in every row only one variable out of the three has a value:

```
var1  var2  var3  sum
NA    NA    300   300
20    NA    NA     20
10    NA    NA     10
```

Do I have to replace the NA's with 0 first in order to compute the sum-column or is there a more elegant way? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df1$sum <- rowSums(df1[grep("^var\\d+", names(df1))], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Also, if there is only a single non-NA element, another option is

```
do.call(pmax, c(df1[1:3], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`, you can also try:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(NA, 20, 10),
                 var2 = c(NA, NA, NA),
                 var3 = c(300, NA, NA))
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, sum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("var1", "var2", "var3")]
```